# Apply for different positions in a company

Tags: job-search

I applied for a position in a company (I am a programmer), let's call this position is **Position A**.

After I applied **Position A**, I just realized that there is **Position B** is opened by that company which has requirement more suits to my skills rather than the one that I applied, **Position A**.

Some days later, the company went back to me to say that the application that I applied, **Position A**, had been closed and they had found other candidate that more suits and **keep my details for future reference if there is suitable job opportunity arise**.

However, a week later, the company sent an email to offer me other position that doesn't suit me at all, **Position C**. Can I reply to the company to apply for **Position B** that suits to me much better?

What I consider is they informed me that they have kept my details but they refer me to a job opening, **Position C**, which doesn't suit my skills at all.

Comment: Sure you can. Why can't you?

Comment: "Can I reply to the company to apply for the position that I have been mentioned above that more suits to me?" Voting to close on the grounds that the post is poorly written. I am not a mind reader.

Comment: JaneS: Please see my edited post, I have consideration in last sentence.
VietnhiPhuvan: lol sorry, I have put more precise detail.

Comment: @RON My comment doesn't change.  You didn't get position A, you can apply for B if you like.  It doesn't matter if they offered you _to apply for_ C in that context.  You could possibly (but not necessarily) read that by contacting you that they are interested in you.  However that could easily be an HR thing and mean very little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you are more than welcome to ask for the other position, they just do not have to accept your request. You will likely have to go back through the selection process, unless the managers for both positions are the same.

In the mean time, you would almost certainly have to give up the position that you were offered.  Whether this is an issue is a matter of personal taste - if you *really* want to work for that specific company it might be worth working a less than ideal job (with the goal of applying for a transfer later), but of course there is the risk you loose other valuable skills in the interim and can never make the transfer.

One thing to keep in mind is that they thought you matched **Position C** best. At a minimum you should write a very good cover letter when asking about the position you want explaining why you are such a good fit for it.

Comment: Please see my edited post. You are mostly correct with your interpretation of what I ask. Btw, I haven't gone through any interview process yet.

Comment: I updated my reply to take the new information into account :)